# Is conda 4.9.2 reporting bogus package conflicts?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda

Since bringing my *Anaconda* infrastructure up-to-date, including updating `conda` to v4.9.2, I'm finding that the installation of one of my packages: `pybert`, is broken.
And, when I peruse the list of reported conflicts, I see things like this:

```
Package six conflicts for:
chaco -> enable[version='>=4.8.0,<4.9'] -> six
scikit-rf -> six
```

which looks bogus to me.
(Both paths lead to `six` with no version constraints; so, how can there be a conflict?)

Am I misreading these conflict reports, or is `conda` broken again?

Thanks!
-db

**Dec. 13, 2020:**

Responding to @merv (Thank you!), here is the complete output from my `conda install ...` command:

```
$ conda install -c dbanas -c conda-forge -c defaults --strict-channel-priority pybert
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                         -

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package cython conflicts for:
pyyaml -> cython
chaco -> cython

Package numpy conflicts for:
pyibis-ami=3.3.3 -> matplotlib -> numpy[version='1.10.*|1.11.*|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.18.1,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.9|>=1.11|1.13.*|1.12.*|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0']
scikit-rf -> matplotlib-base -> numpy[version='1.10.*|1.11.*|1.12.*|1.13.*|>=1.11|>=1.11.*|>=1.11.3,<2.0a0|>=1.14.6,<2.0a0|>=1.15.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.18.4,<2.0a0|>=1.18.1,<2.0a0|>=1.12.1,<2.0a0|>=1.9.*|>=1.9|>=1.8|>=1.7|>=1.13.3,<2.0a0|>=1.9.3,<1.10.0a0|>=1.15.1,<2.0a0']
chaco -> enable[version='>=4.8.0,<4.9'] -> numpy
scikit-rf -> numpy

Package gdbm conflicts for:
kiwisolver -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.2'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']
python -> pypy3.7=7.3.3 -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']
pyyaml -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.2'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']

Package setuptools conflicts for:
chaco -> cython -> setuptools
pyibis-ami=3.3.3 -> matplotlib -> setuptools
pyyaml -> cython -> setuptools
scikit-rf -> ipython -> setuptools[version='>=18.5']
python -> pip -> setuptools

Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python -> ca-certificates
pyyaml -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
pyside2 -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
kiwisolver -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0'] -> ca-certificates
scikit-rf -> python -> ca-certificates

Package matplotlib-base conflicts for:
scikit-rf -> matplotlib-base
scikit-rf -> matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='2.1.2|2.1.2|2.1.2|2.2.3|2.2.3|2.2.3|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|3.0.1|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.3|3.0.3|3.0.3|3.0.3|3.1.0|3.1.0|3.1.0|3.1.0|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.3|3.1.3|3.1.3|>=3.2.0,<3.2.1.0a0|>=3.2.1,<3.2.2.0a0|>=3.2.2,<3.2.3.0a0|>=3.3.0,<3.3.1.0a0|>=3.3.1,<3.3.2.0a0|>=3.3.2,<3.3.3.0a0|>=3.3.3,<3.3.4.0a0|>=2.2.5,<2.2.6.0a0|3.1.3|3.1.3|3.1.3|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2',build='py38h9aa3819_1|py36h9aa3819_0|py37h9aa3819_0|py36h31f9439_1|py37h31f9439_1|py36hd64abcd_1|py37h31f9439_1|py27h11da6c2_2|py36hf043ca5_1000|py36hf043ca5_1001|py37hf043ca5_1002|py36hf043ca5_0|py37hf043ca5_0|py36habd5b94_1|py37habd5b94_1|py37h3a684a6_1|py37h3a684a6_1|py36h11da6c2_2|py37h11da6c2_0|py38h11da6c2_0|py36h11da6c2_1|py37h11da6c2_1|py38h11da6c2_1|py37h11da6c2_0|py38h11da6c2_0|py36h11da6c2_0|py36h11da6c2_0|py38h11da6c2_2|py37h11da6c2_2|py38h11da6c2_1|py36h3a684a6_1|py36h3a684a6_0|py37h3a684a6_0|py36h3a684a6_1|py36habd5b94_0|py37habd5b94_0|py36hf043ca5_1002|py37hf043ca5_1001|py36hebca740_1001|py36h11da6c2_2|py38h11da6c2_2|py37h11da6c2_2|py36h31f9439_1|py27h31f9439_1|py27h3a684a6_0|py37h3a684a6_0|py36h3a684a6_0|py37hd64abcd_1|py27hd64abcd_1|py27h31f9439_1|py38h9aa3819_0|py36h9aa3819_1|py37h9aa3819_1']
pyibis-ami=3.3.3 -> matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='2.1.2|2.1.2|2.1.2|2.2.3|2.2.3|2.2.3|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|2.2.4|3.0.1|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.2|3.0.3|3.0.3|3.0.3|3.0.3|3.1.0|3.1.0|3.1.0|3.1.0|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.1|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.3|3.1.3|3.1.3|>=3.2.0,<3.2.1.0a0|>=3.2.1,<3.2.2.0a0|>=3.2.2,<3.2.3.0a0|>=3.3.0,<3.3.1.0a0|>=3.3.1,<3.3.2.0a0|>=3.3.2,<3.3.3.0a0|>=3.3.3,<3.3.4.0a0|>=2.2.5,<2.2.6.0a0|3.1.3|3.1.3|3.1.3|3.1.2|3.1.2|3.1.2',build='py38h9aa3819_1|py36h9aa3819_0|py37h9aa3819_0|py36h31f9439_1|py37h31f9439_1|py36hd64abcd_1|py37h31f9439_1|py27h11da6c2_2|py36hf043ca5_1000|py36hf043ca5_1001|py37hf043ca5_1002|py36hf043ca5_0|py37hf043ca5_0|py36habd5b94_1|py37habd5b94_1|py37h3a684a6_1|py37h3a684a6_1|py36h11da6c2_2|py37h11da6c2_0|py38h11da6c2_0|py36h11da6c2_1|py37h11da6c2_1|py38h11da6c2_1|py37h11da6c2_0|py38h11da6c2_0|py36h11da6c2_0|py36h11da6c2_0|py38h11da6c2_2|py37h11da6c2_2|py38h11da6c2_1|py36h3a684a6_1|py36h3a684a6_0|py37h3a684a6_0|py36h3a684a6_1|py36habd5b94_0|py37habd5b94_0|py36hf043ca5_1002|py37hf043ca5_1001|py36hebca740_1001|py36h11da6c2_2|py38h11da6c2_2|py37h11da6c2_2|py36h31f9439_1|py27h31f9439_1|py27h3a684a6_0|py37h3a684a6_0|py36h3a684a6_0|py37hd64abcd_1|py27hd64abcd_1|py27h31f9439_1|py38h9aa3819_0|py36h9aa3819_1|py37h9aa3819_1']

Package libpng conflicts for:
pyside2 -> qt[version='>=5.12.9,<5.13.0a0'] -> libpng[version='>=1.6.32,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.35,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0']
scikit-rf -> matplotlib-base -> libpng[version='>=1.6.23,<1.7|>=1.6.35,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.36,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.32,<1.7.0a0']
pyibis-ami=3.3.3 -> matplotlib -> libpng[version='>=1.6.23,<1.7|>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.36,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.35,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0|>=1.6.32,<1.7.0a0']

Package libcxxabi conflicts for:
pyside2 -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi[version='4.0.1|4.0.1|8.0.0|8.0.0|8.0.0|8.0.0|8.0.1',build='hcfea43d_1|1|2|0|4|3|hebd6815_0']
python -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi[version='4.0.1|4.0.1|8.0.0|8.0.0|8.0.0|8.0.0|8.0.1',build='hcfea43d_1|1|2|0|4|3|hebd6815_0']
kiwisolver -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi[version='4.0.1|4.0.1|8.0.0|8.0.0|8.0.0|8.0.0|8.0.1',build='hcfea43d_1|1|2|0|4|3|hebd6815_0']

Package six conflicts for:
chaco -> enable[version='>=4.8.0,<4.9'] -> six
scikit-rf -> six

Package kiwisolver conflicts for:
scikit-rf -> matplotlib-base -> kiwisolver[version='>=1.0.1']
kiwisolver
Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

And here are versions for each "conflicting" package mentioned in that output, which I believe meet all dependents' requirements:

| Package | Version | Build |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cython | (any) | (any) |
| numpy | 1.19.2 | (any) |
| gdbm | 1.18 | (any) |
| setuptools | 18.5 | (any) |
| ca-certificates | (any) | (any) |
| matplotlib-base | 2.1.2 | (any) |
| libpng | 1.6.35 | (any) |
| libcxxabi | 4.0.1 | hcfea43d_1 |
| six | (any) | (any) |
| kiwisolver | 1.0.1 | (any) |

I'm very curious: does anyone reading this disagree with any of my claimed working versions, above?
(I'm still wondering if I don't quite understand how to interpret this output.)

Judging from my own experience, here, and from what I've found while searching on this topic, it seems likely that `conda` is currently broken, in this regard (i.e. - identifying true conflicts).
Who are the right folks to talk to about lending a hand in getting this fixed?

Thanks!
-db

Comment: Yeah, it's terribly confusing, but this isn't new behavior. Conda simply lists every package that has two or more dependency chains that lead to the same package. Consequently, most of what gets output is not a conflict; however, there should be at least one package that actually has a legitimate conflict.

Comment: Thanks, @merv! I've edited my original post in response to your comment.

Comment: You can report it as [an issue on the repo](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues). I do find it curious that no entry for `python` is being displayed. Having looked through your packages, `parsec` only has a Python 3.7 version, whereas everything else is strictly Python 3.8, so I kinda suspect that could be the real issue. Nevertheless, Conda should properly catch that.

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the `parsec` package was locked to Python 3.7, while everything else was requesting 3.8.
I don't know why `conda` wasn't reporting this in some obvious way in its "conflicts" report.